# How to Map (using AutoMapper) entities that have a ForeignKey in ASP.NET CORE 3.1.1 (C#,EntityFrameworkCore)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have this function in my controller that creates a an entity:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ConnectionDBResponse), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ConnectionDBResponse>> PostConnectionDB([FromBody] CreateConnectionDBQuery query)
    {
        var connectionDBs = _mapper.Map<ConnectionDBDataModel>(query);
        _context.ConnectionDB.Add(connectionDBs);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var connectionDBResponse = _mapper.Map<ConnectionDBResponse>(connectionDBs);
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetAllConnectionDB), new { id = connectionDBs.Id }, connectionDBResponse);
    }
```

For that I'm mapping between these two classes:
The response Class:

```
public class CreateConnectionDBQuery
{
    public string ServerType { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string port { get; set; }
    public string AuthType { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DBName { get; set; }
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public ScheduleConfigResponse ScheduleConfig { get; set; }
    public Boolean hasEmails { get; set; }
    public EmailConfigResponse EmailConfig { get; set; }
}

public class CreateScheduleConfigQuery
{
    public string HourOfSave { get; set; }
    public int NumDaysInDB { get; set; }
    public CreateConnectionDBQuery ConnDB { get; set; }
    public int ConnDBForeignKey { get; set; }
}

public class CreateEmailConfigQuery
{
    public string SuccesEmail { get; set; }
    public string FailureEmail { get; set; }
    public CreateConnectionDBQuery ConnDB { get; set; }
    public int ConnDBForeignKey { get; set; }
}
```

And the dataModel Class:

```
[Table("ConnectionDB")]
public class ConnectionDBDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ServerType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string port { get; set; }
    public string AuthType { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DBName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public ScheduleConfigDataModel ScheduleConfig { get; set; }
    public Boolean hasEmails { get; set; }
    public EmailConfigDataModel EmailConfig { get; set; }
}

[Table("ScheduleConfig")]
public class ScheduleConfigDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HourOfSave { get; set; }
    public int NumDaysInDB { get; set; }

    public int ConnDBForeignKey { get; set; }
    public ConnectionDBDataModel ConnDB { get; set; }
}

[Table("EmailConfig")]
public class EmailConfigDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SuccesEmail { get; set; }
    public string FailureEmail { get; set; }

    public int ConnDBForeignKey { get; set; }
    public ConnectionDBDataModel ConnDB { get; set; }
}
```

For that I'm using the AutoMapper as following:

```
        #region ConnectionDB

        CreateMap<ConnectionDBDataModel, ConnectionDBResponse>();

        CreateMap<CreateConnectionDBQuery, ConnectionDBDataModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<UpdateConnectionDBQuery, ConnectionDBDataModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

        #endregion

        #region ScheduleConfig

        CreateMap<ScheduleConfigDataModel, ScheduleConfigResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ConnDBForeignKey, opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<CreateScheduleConfigQuery, ScheduleConfigDataModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ConnDBForeignKey, opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<UpdateScheduleConfigQuery, ScheduleConfigDataModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

        #endregion ScheduleConfig

        #region EmailConfig

        CreateMap<EmailConfigDataModel, EmailConfigResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ConnDBForeignKey, opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<CreateEmailConfigQuery, EmailConfigDataModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ConnDBForeignKey, opt => opt.Ignore());

        CreateMap<UpdateEmailConfigQuery, EmailConfigDataModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

        #endregion
```

But when I try to create this element it gives me an error saying that it's coming from an invalid Mapping as shown in the screen bellow:

[image]

I have tried to Ignore the Foreign Key (because my guess that this problem is coming from the foreignKey) using this line of code : `.ForMember(dest => dest.ConnDBForeignKey, opt => opt.Ignore());` , but I guess it's not the way to solve that problem.
Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: The mapping error is from the `CreateConnectionDBQuery` class. Can you show that instead of the `ConnectionDBResponse` class?

Comment: Yes sure, I'm going to edit the question Right now

Comment: Can you add a `ScheduleConfigResponse` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because when mapping `CreateConnectionDBQuery` to `ConnectionDBDataModel`, there is no mapping defined for the types of the `ScheduleConfig` properties.

I'm guessing that in your `CreateConnectionDBQuery`, your `ScheduleConfig` property should be of type `CreateScheduleConfigQuery` instead of `ScheduleConfigResponse`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the models, you could add a mapping configuration from `ScheduleConfigResponse` to `ScheduleConfigDataModel`. But that doesn't seem very intuitive.